# Range in Word keeps changing when tables update

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I create multiple tables in word and populate them with data from an excel file. 
The coding is done in Excel VBA. I use the Range object in the word document to identify where to insert the next table. 
So i add a table, populate it and insert a new row below it.

I then store the end of the current table range as a reference for adding the next table. So far no problem.
But when I insert a lot of data into a table and then change the width of the columns, this takes some time in word. So the reference I stored before might not be valid any more once I want to create the next table.

The whole document changed in the meantime and the position I stored doesn't exist any more. Is there a way around this? Currently I wait for 2 Seconds to not get the error.

```
Public Function PrintWord(Word, Document, Start As Integer) As Integer
Dim intNoOfRows
Dim intNoOfColumns



intNoOfRows = 7
intNoOfColumns = 2
x = Start
Set objRange = Document.Range(x, x)   
Set objTable = Document.Tables.Add(objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)

objTable.Borders.Enable = True

objTable.Cell(1, 1) = [...] ' This is where I populate the table and change the width etc.

Dim y As Integer

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) ' if I wait here, everything works, if not the Range for the next table is some times not valid


y = objTable.Range.End + 1 ' Store the end of the table as a reference for the next one


Document.Range(x, y).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3

objTable.Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = 3 ' wdPreferredWidthPoints
objTable.Columns(1).PreferredWidth = Word.CentimetersToPoints(3.5)
objTable.Columns(2).PreferredWidthType = 3 ' wdPreferredWidthPoints
objTable.Columns(2).PreferredWidth = Word.CentimetersToPoints(13)

objTable.Select


Word.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, count:=1 ' Move below table
Word.Selection.TypeParagraph



PrintWord = y ' Returns the position for the next Table
```

End Function

Comment: Hoping this isn't a stupid work around, but when I insert a table to word I do it as a find/replace, where I have unique identifiers for each of the entries.  The sizing doesn't matter, but if my identifier is gone, then there is no insert of data.  If set-up this way, you could avoid the positional requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but have a dynamic data set, that i insert into various documents. So this won't work very well.

Comment: Why are you storing the *position* of the `Range` instead of the `Range` itself?

Comment: Due to lazyness of declaration and handling of the range... But what do I say? Case closed, problem solved. Thanks a lot!!